# Is it possible to override a super property/method to make it private in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing a UITextView subclass, and setting the UITextView delegate as self. I don't want the client to be able to set my delegate (because otherwise the subclass becomes pointless). Is there a way I could make the `delegate` property private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can override the visibility of a property declared in a superclass. But, you can override the `delegate` property itself in your subclass, to prevent callers from setting the delegate at runtime:

```
override var delegate: UITextViewDelegate? {
    get { return super.delegate }
    set {
        // either ignore this, or raise an error
    }
}
```

Then, when you are setting delegate to self in your subclass, make sure to use `super`:

```
super.delegate = self
```